# MySQLi condition not properly working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When user try to register, I am checking first table device, if there any device_id available I want provide user trial=0 and if there no any device_id, I want insert device_id in that table and want user trial=1, but currently its always set trial=1 and inserting device_id in table device.
My current code is like below

```
$serial = $POST["serial"];
    $fcm = $POST["fcm"];
    $trial  = 0;
    $trial_sql = "SELECT FROM device WHERE device_id = $serial";
        $trial_result = mysqli_query($conn, $trial_sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($trial_result) == 0) {
         $device_sql = "INSERT INTO device(device_id) VALUES('$serial')";
         if($conn->query($device_sql)){
             $trial = 1;
            }   
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user(name, email, password, device_id, trial, fcm) VALUES('$name', '$email', '$password', '$serial', $trial, '$fcm')";
    if($conn->query($sql)) {
        $response["code"] = 1;
    }
    return json_encode($response);
```

Let me know if someone can correct my mistake. 
Thanks

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thanks for your comment and suggestion. I will do it before I am make live. Let me know if You can help me for solve my located issue. Thanks

Comment: You should also make sure that the `device_id` field has a unique constraint in the database schema.

Comment: If device_id is a string, you would need quotes round the value n the select (or use prepared statements)

Comment: @NigelRen You have solved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You both need to specify a column to select as well as include quotes round the device_id...

```
$trial_sql = "SELECT * FROM device WHERE device_id = '$serial'";
```

The quotes would have not been a problem if you used prepared statements.

Comment: Turn the tide against teaching/propagating sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM device
```

Or

```
SELECT columnA, columnB FROM device
```

Your first query is not valid because it doesn't say what columns it wants to select from device table.

Comment: Hi! Its still same issue.

Comment: You need to do "SELECT device_id FROM..." in that first one then

Comment: I havent used non-prepared statements in a while now. I stick to prepare, bind params, bind result, and execute. It makes it very easy to see where everything goes and works. http://wbr.bz/QueryPro is a good place to start